# App oddities when the app is cleared from the cache

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello all and thanks for reading.

This question is kind of a follow on question from my original post here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828412/main-activity-progress-bars-and-strike-through-text-reset-after-a-period-of-app. However, I've now worked out what's going on but still need some advice on how to solve it.

Just to recap...

Basically I have written a media player app that uses a number of standard progress bars which are created programmatically underneath each track title in the playlist. Each progress bar tracks the progress of the song its sits underneath in the playlist.

I also use the following code in my manifest to make sure the app always returns to the same main activity.

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Now the problem I have is that when the user returns to the home screen and then relaunches the app after a period of 30 to 60 minutes although everything else is as it was - if the progress bar was only partially full (i.e. the track has been paused or stopped halfway through) all of a sudden its jumped to 100%.

I discovered that this happens when the apps cached process is bumped off the end of the list by other apps. I.e. I can recreate the issue straight away by pausing the app and then opening loads of other apps and then going back to it. I also noticed that when it no longer appears in the cached process list "oncreate" also gets called so it looks like the app has been closed and its essentially recreating the activity. However, what is odd is that the progress bars that have previously been set to some value suddenly get recreated with progress set to 100%. Progress

Now if they are being recreated surely their progress should default to 0? I even tried setting the progress when they are created to 0 (i.e. myprogbar.setProgress=(0) but this seemed to make no difference.

How can I...

a. Ensure that the progress bars are set to 0 when they are created?

b. Check during oncreate if the app is already running and destroy all previous versions of it?

c. Ensure that the app doesn't get dropped from the cached processes?

d. Some other way of solving the issue.

I appreciate I could probably create a loop that loops through the progress bars once they have been created and resets them but I'm trying to understand where the progress bars are getting this value of 100% and how this relates to the app being pushed out of the cached processes list.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I never worked out why this was actually happening but just in case someone else ever gets the same issue I found a work around.

Basically I set up a timer to loop through all of the progress bars on screen and reset them when the activity loads. Not elegant or smart but it works.

```
    final Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProgressBar temppb;
                    for (int i = 0; i < (totalnumberofprogressbars); i++) {
                            temppb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(i + 1);
                            temppb.setProgress(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            myTimer.cancel();
        }
    }, 50,50);
```